Ajax live search in header on wagtail/Django
I recently just started learning Python, Wagtail and Django.
There was a need to create a live search in the header of the site, but I just can’t get it to work correctly; as a result of the search, the entire page with search results is loaded.
Here's the code I put a lot of effort into:
in header.html:
<div class="block_search">
<input type="text" class="search_input searchbox"  id="search_header" value="" placeholder="Поиск товара..." name="q"  >
{% include "tags/header_search.html" %}
</div>
        

header_search.html:
{% load static wagtailcore_tags header_tags %}

<div id="search_box-result">
    {% get_header_search as search_result%}
    {% for result in search_result %}
    {{result.title}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>


Jquery:
<script>
        
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#search_header').on('input',function(e){
                        var search_result = $("#search_header").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            cache: true,
                            url: '',
                            data: {"search": search_result},
                            success: function (response) {
                                $("#search_box-result").replaceWith(response)
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    
                    
                });
</script>

header_tags.py:
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_header_search(context):
    request = context['request']
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search_query = request.GET.get("search", None)
        print(search_query)
        if search_query:
            search_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)
        else:
            search_results = Page.objects.none()
        return search_results

`In browser:
enter image description here
enter image description here

Can you please take a look at the network tab in your browser's developer tools and tell us if it is actually making an AJAX call (an item in the 'Fetch/XHR' section) or is making a regular request (an item in the Doc section). The behavior you describe sounds like you are making a regular request. You seem to be trying to handle the search in a template tag which seems odd to me but before looking at that, I want to know what your current code does.

Adding in question

I understand that I cannot send header_search.html and search results separately in the response. I tried through render, JsonResponse, HttpResponse but nothing works

I think you need a way to identify where is an ajax call or a user call from a browser. I want that too. Considering what is the difference between ajax and user browser request I found this link
When I can differentiate between those call I made this code:
def is_ajax(request):
  if(request.headers.get('SEC_FETCH_SITE') == "same-origin"):
    return True
  return False    

class Model(Page):
  description = models.CharField(max_length=511)
  def get_template(self, request):
    if is_ajax(request):
      return "base/model_ajax.html"
    return "base/model_page.html"

When you look up your get_header_search tag, you can differentiate if it's ajax or not. Maybe when it's ajax, you can use another template or a JsonResponse, and when isn't, you can load a different template.
When you ask by ajax, you need an URL, that url in wagtail could be a Wagtail API syntax or just a static url that could be rendered with the django context processor. In my case, it was for a static URL rendered inside the template, when I click it, I make an ajax call to a document specifically for a template, and when it wasn't . I just put a normal template.
I hope it helps.

my solution to the problem
Wagtail has ajax_template, it specifies a template that will respond to any Ajax request, but it specifies one template.
I overridden the function for getting a template and, depending on the get request, displays the desired template.
I don't know how correct this is, but it works without problems.
class CategoryPage(Page):
parent_page_types = ['catalog.CatalogPage','category.CategoryPage']
subpage_types = ['category.CategoryPage','product.ProductPage']
def get_template(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.headers.get("x-requested-with") == "XMLHttpRequest":
        if request.GET.get("search", None) != None:
            self.ajax_template = 'tags/header_search.html'
        elif request.GET.getlist('platforms_ids[]', None) != None or request.GET.getlist('types_ids[]', None) != None or request.GET.get('page[]', 1) != None:
            self.ajax_template = "tags/category_filtered_products_for_ajax.html"
        return self.ajax_template or self.template
    else:
        return self.template

